# FORTRAN wipes arg values between function calls?

Tags: arguments, fortran, scope

So strange. Does FORTRAN require variables to be reinitialized after they've been sent as parameters? I kept getting a segmentation fault whenever I'd send the same arguments to another subroutine. I discovered that the argument values were being wiped between the first call and the second, with no reassignment statements on the arguments between function calls or even in either function. The scope of these arguments is limited to the main program (I'm not using any COMMON blocks).

I can't post code right now as I'm writing from my phone, but any ideas? The temporary workaround is to reassign the values right before calling the second function.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I agree with Stefano, it's impossible to be sure what's going wrong without seeing code.  Are you specifying the intent of your arguments ?  (You should be.)  When you write that the scope of the arguments is limited to the main program, but that you are passing these variables as arguments to sub-programs, you are confusing me -- if you pass an argument to a sub-program its scope is extended, though it may seem to have a different name.

Comment: Agreed. The scope is extended. Combine that with call by reference and an overlooked value change in the subroutine, and you have a recipe for segfault.

Comment: And re: "no code", I hate not having tethering when I'm away from wi-fi... But what a first-world problem. At least I have food and indoor plumbing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fortran passes arguments by reference, so if you are modifying them in the first subroutine, they will be changed in the caller.

Comment: I didn't think I was modifying them in the subroutines, but upon closer inspection found that I was. Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you can, specifying `intent(in)` as part of the variable declaration in the function can help the compiler check if you're accidentally assigning to something you shouldn't.

Answer (score 3):

No Fortran doesn't zap variables when they have been used as arguments in a subroutine call.

However, arguments passed by reference can have their values changed by the called subroutine.

Try printing the variables before the second call. Have a look at how the first subroutine uses the parameters.

Just my ¤0.02 worth - it's decades since I looked at Fortran (IV).

Comment: I don't know why, but each time I read "Fortran Four", I remember "Number Nine" (Pink Floyd). BTW I still remember loading FIV programs from a punched cards.

Comment: I still have IBM 80-column punched cards somewhere with Fortran IV on them (if bookworms haven't reduced them to dust) - cue Monty Python Yorkshireman sketch.

Comment: Indeed, 'tis by reference, as @lijie pointed out as well. I forgot that they were in fact being changed. Thanks to all for your efforts!